# Joining two tables together creates cartesian product on one field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having trouble with a SUM function that keeps overcounting my query.

I have two tables:

- Table 1: Tracking Information, this can have a 1-N relationship with a sales order (IE- many tracking numbers can be generated from one sales order ID)
- Table 2: Sales Order information - this contains the products and quantities ordered for the sales order.

Here is a simplified table of each, there are other columns, but these are the relevant ones:

| SOTranId | TrackingNbr | ShipDate | NetAmtDue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 8/16/22 | 7.92 |
| 1 | 2 | 8/19/22 | 8.15 |
| 1 | 3 | 8/16/22 | 7.92 |
| 1 | 4 | 8/16/22 | 7.92 |
| 1 | 5 | 8/16/22 | 7.92 |
| 1 | 6 | 8/16/22 | 7.92 |
| 1 | 7 | 8/16/22 | 7.92 |
| 2 | 8 | 5/27/22 | 6.34 |
| 1 | 9 | 8/16/22 | 7.92 |
| 1 | 10 | 8/17/22 | 7.92 |
| 1 | 11 | 8/16/22 | 7.92 |
| 1 | 12 | 8/16/22 | 8.15 |
| 1 | 13 | 8/16/22 | 7.92 |
| 3 | 14 | 8/19/22 | 8.18 |

| Tran ID | Transaction Line | Sales Description | Item Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | TUBES | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | WIPES | 24 |
| 3 | 1 | BANDS - 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | BANDS - 2 | 1 |

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT  SUM(t.netamtdue) as freightcost,count(distinct t.TrackingNbr) as number_of_shipments, DATEPART(year,ShipDate) as Year1, COUNT(DISTINCT t.ORDERID) as number_of_orders, DATEPART(week, t.ShipDate) as week_shipped, SUM(s.Item Count) as number_of_items
  FROM [Tracking] t
  
 
 LEFT JOIN (
        Select [Tran ID], Sum([Item Count]) as number_of_items
        FROM [Sales Order Information] 
        GROUP BY [Tran ID]) s
        ON s.[Tran ID] = t.SOTranID

  
  GROUP BY  DATEPART(year,ShipDate), DATEPART(week, t.ShipDate)
```

When manually counting, I would expect this to give me $95.5 for freight amount, 12 for tracking number, 1 for sales order, and 24 for the item quantity.

Instead it gives me 288 item quantity, but correct everything else.

I know it's multiplying the number of tracking numbers by the item count, but I can't figure out how to rewrite this to avoid that problem. The query has worked historically for count of shipments and orders, but when I try to add in the itemqty field it breaks.

Comment: YOur query reference two tables, but your question only provides sample data for one of those tables. I *suspect* you have a many to one (or many to many) join.

Comment: Hi Thom - The second table somehow got formatted into one line under the first table (I'm a newb at formatting in stack overflow) where the line shows: Tran ID Product Description Item Count 682 WIPES 24

Comment: The problem was your lack of markdown, @AlexB . When I [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/76174852/2) your question I noticed the unformated first table, but the second table wasn't as apparent. When submitting a question, you should take a moment to check it actually looks correct in the preview.

Comment: You have a one to many relationship. You shouldn't be `SUM`ing `number_of_items` in the outer `SELECT`, you've already `SUM`ed it.

Comment: You can starting rethinking your whole concept, because depending on when the shippings were sent, you will get duplicate number of items sent. Consider order with 10 products shipped in two different months. How do you know which products were shipped in specific months. As you do now, they will count twice

Comment: Thanks Thom - the problem I was running into without the SUM function in the outer select is I was getting the error "not in an aggregate function or group by statement". The group by recommendation works below, but it gives me unique rows of week + number of item, when I want the sum of all items shipped in a week.

Answer (score 0):

Just like [Thom A](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2029983/thom-a) commented, you don't need to SUM number_of_items on the SELECT, you just need to add it on the SELECT and on the GROUP BY clause

```
SELECT SUM(t.netamtdue) AS freightcost,
    count(DISTINCT t.TrackingNbr) AS number_of_shipments,
    DATEPART(year, ShipDate) AS Year1,
    COUNT(DISTINCT t.ORDERID) AS number_of_orders,
    DATEPART(week, t.ShipDate) AS week_shipped,
    s.number_of_items
FROM [Tracking] t
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [Tran ID],
        Sum([Item Count]) AS number_of_items
    FROM [Sales Order Information]
    GROUP BY [Tran ID]
    ) s ON s.[Tran ID] = t.OrderID
GROUP BY DATEPART(year, ShipDate), DATEPART(week, t.ShipDate), s.number_of_items
```

Comment: So this worked for just my mini-example of one sales order, but when I try to run the query for the larger date set now it's grouping on the number_of_items and creating additional row results. I'd like for the sum of all items to be aggregated up to the week.

Comment: Then provide a better example, @AlexB . As you are grouping on the Tran ID you won't get more than one row per that, so what you state doesn't tally with what the SQL is.

Comment: @ThomA - I've updated the dataset to be a better representation of what I'm looking at. Appreciate all of the help with markdown and other advice.

Answer (score -1):

You need `SUM(number_of_items)` and not `Sum([Item Count])`.